# How do I compare nodes using xslt code?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a sample xml

```
<ConditionTable>
    <incondition name = "abc" />
    <incondition name = "xyz" />
    <outconditon name = "abc" />
    <outcondition name = "xyz" />
    <job name = "hello world" />
</ConditionTable>

<ConditionTable>
    <incondition name = "abc" />
    <incondition name = "xyz" />
    <outcondition name = "xyz" />
    <outcondition name = "xyz" />
    <job name = "hello world2" />
</ConditionTable>
```

I am trying to write an xslt such that, **If ALL the incondition name has at least one matching outcondition name**, then the job name gets printed. So far I have something like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="ConditionTable/incondition ">
    <xsl:if test="(current()/@name = ../outcondition/@name)"
        <xsl:value-of select="../job/@name" />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But it prints for both the job names. I should not print the job name if at least one incondition is not satisfied.

Comment: outconditon != outcondition

Answer (score 0):

Make your test negative - for example:

```
<xsl:for-each select="ConditionTable">
    <xsl:variable name="t" select="." />
    <xsl:if test="not(incondition[not(key('out', @name, $t))])">
        <xsl:value-of select="job/@name" />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

where the key would be defined as:

```
<xsl:key name="out" match="outcondition" use="@name"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

> If ALL the incondition name has at least one matching outcondition name

The most direct way of expressing that is the XPath 2.0 expression

```
test="every $i in incondition satisfies 
        some $o in outcondition satisfies
           $i eq $o"
```

You can abbreviate this by taking advantage of the fact that `A=$b` means `some $a in A satisfies $a eq $b`, giving you

```
test="every $i in incondition satisfies 
        $i = outcondition
```

If you want to make it even more concise, you can take advantage of the fact that `every X satisfies Y` converts to `not(some X satisfies not(Y))`, which gives you

```
test="not(some $i in incondition satisfies not($i = outcondition))"
```

which further simplifies to:

```
test="not(incondition[not(.=outcondition)])"
```

but that might be a bit terse for some tastes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the check for 'incondition' to 'outcondition' should only be done within the same ConditionTable.

Try this XSLT 1.0:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="ConditionTable">
        <xsl:if test ="not( incondition[ not( ../outcondition/@name = @name ) ] )" >
            <xsl:value-of select="../job/@name" />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
```